# Insert image from Mac finder into HTML

Tags: html, image, responsive-images

I am trying to add an image from my downloads in my Mac Finder (using HTML) but the image won't show up when I've tried.

I opened the image with Chrome to get a link: Users/oliviamartin/Downloads/flatweb.jpg

And formatted it like this:

```
<img src="file:///Users/oliviamartin/Downloads/flatweb.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
```

But no image appears after putting into the code.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
<img src="file:///Users/oliviamartin/Downloads/flatweb.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
```

Comment: Not sure why the code isn't showing up: here it is <img src="file:///Users/oliviamartin/Downloads/flatweb.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">

Comment: Are you serving the HTML in which you’ve included this markup with a proper HTTP server? If so, your browser will disallow `file:///` links as it would otherwise represent a very large security risk if any arbitrary website could read files from your filesystem.

Comment: Who else do you expect to be viewing the HTML page? They are unlikely to have a /Users/oliviamartin folder on their computers, And even less likely to have a Downloads/flatweb.jpg file therein if they somehow do.

Comment: I tried on my Mac and it works.  The question is: how do you open the HTML file? You just "throw" it to the navigator window? You use the web server on the Mac? You put this HTML on a web server?

Answer (score 0):

If you are hosting this HTML page on a local server (which I believe you are) then place your image within that directory `Users/oliviamartin/documents/github/project/imgs/flatweb.jpg`. You can then serve that image from the directory with a relative url `/imgs/flatweb.jpg`.